# Error php: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by

Tags: php, phpmailer

tengo un formulario que envía un email al correo electrónico.Tengo la pagina web subida a hostinger y de un dia a otro sin tocar nada me da este fallo:
Creo que el error esta en el header,al intentar redirigir la pagina al index.

Gracias!

> Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by

```
<?php

$first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
$last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
$portal = $_POST['portal'];
$piso = $_POST['piso'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$incidencia = $_POST['incidencia'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$archivo = $_FILES['adjunto'];


require("archivosformulario/class.phpmailer.php");
//Create a new PHPMailer instance
$mail = new PHPMailer;
//Tell PHPMailer to use SMTP
$mail->isSMTP();
//Enable SMTP debugging
// 0 = off (for production use)
// 1 = client messages
// 2 = client and server messages
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
//Set the hostname of the mail server
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
// use
// $mail->Host = gethostbyname('smtp.gmail.com');
// if your network does not support SMTP over IPv6
//Set the SMTP port number - 587 for authenticated TLS, a.k.a. RFC4409 SMTP submission
$mail->Port = 587;
//Set the encryption system to use - ssl (deprecated) or tls
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
//Whether to use SMTP authentication
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
//Username to use for SMTP authentication - use full email address for gmail
$mail->Username = "correopersonal";
//Password to use for SMTP authentication
$mail->Password = "contraseña";
//Set who the message is to be sent from
$mail->setFrom($email, $first_name);
//Set an alternative reply-to address
$mail->addReplyTo($email, $first_name);
//Set who the message is to be sent to
$mail->addAddress('correo', 'minombre');
//Set the subject line
$mail->Subject = 'INCIDENCIA NUEVA: ' . $incidencia;
//Read an HTML message body from an external file, convert referenced images to embedded,
//convert HTML into a basic plain-text alternative body
$mail->msgHTML(file_get_contents('contents.html'), __DIR__);

//Replace the plain text body with one created manually
$mail->AltBody = 'This is a plain-text message body';
     $mail->Body     =  
    "Esto es un correo generado desde la web, si quiere mas informacion contacte con:  \n<br". 
    "\n<br> Nombre: $first_name \n<br />".  

    "Apellido: $last_name \n<br />".  
    "Portal: $portal \n<br />".
    "Piso: $piso \n<br />".
    "Email: $email \n<br />".
    "Telefono: $phone \n<br />".  
    "Incidencia: $incidencia \n<br />".
    "Mensaje: $message \n<br />";
//Attach an image file
$mail->AddAttachment($archivo['tmp_name'], $archivo['name']);

//send the message, check for errors
if (!$mail->send()) {
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
     header('Location: index.html');
} else {
    echo "Message sent!";
       header('Location: index.html');
    //Section 2: IMAP
    //Uncomment these to save your message in the 'Sent Mail' folder.
    //if (save_mail($mail)) {
      //  echo "Message saved!";
    //}

}
//Section 2: IMAP
//IMAP commands requires the PHP IMAP Extension, found at: https://php.net/manual/en/imap.setup.php
//Function to call which uses the PHP imap_*() functions to save messages: https://php.net/manual/en/book.imap.php
//You can use imap_getmailboxes($imapStream, '/imap/ssl') to get a list of available folders or labels, this can
//be useful if you are trying to get this working on a non-Gmail IMAP server.
function save_mail($mail)
{
    //You can change 'Sent Mail' to any other folder or tag
    $path = "{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}[Gmail]/Sent Mail";
    //Tell your server to open an IMAP connection using the same username and password as you used for SMTP
    $imapStream = imap_open($path, $mail->Username, $mail->Password);
    $result = imap_append($imapStream, $path, $mail->getSentMIMEMessage());
    imap_close($imapStream);
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: prueba comentando los echo que tienes delante de cada header

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Donde usas la función header verifica si la puedes lanzar con éste método `headers_sent()`.

> `headers_sent()` retornará FALSE si no se han enviado encabezados HTTP
>   o de lo contrario TRUE.

```
    <?php // Si no se han enviado encabezados, enviar
    if (!headers_sent()) {
        header('Location: http://www.example.com/');
        exit;
    }else{//si se han enviado haremos redirect desde javascript
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
        echo 'window.location.href="'.$filename.'";';
        echo '</script>';
        echo '<noscript>';
        echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url='.$filename.'" />';
        echo '</noscript>';
    }

?>
```

[Documentación.](http://php.net/headers_sent)

Answer (score 1):

Estás usando `echo` antes de redirigir:

```
if (!$mail->send()) {
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    header('Location: index.html');
} else {
    echo "Message sent!";
    header('Location: index.html');
}
```

El `echo` de por sí imprime el contenido y por tanto envía los header correspondientes (por ejemplo que el `content-type` es `text/plain`). Enviados esos headers, no puedes añadir headers nuevos sobre la marcha.

En vez de usar `header` para redirigir puedes usar lo que dice @sakulino, imprimir una etiqueta `script` que redirija desde el browser.

Comment: Al final, ni quitando el echo ni de ningún método funcionaba.He tenido que cambiar el método y ponerlo con script ,window.location.href. Muchas gracias

Comment: Esta es la respuesta correcta, le sale ese error debido a lo que se está explicando acá, esta debería ser la respuesta aprovada. En definitiva, cualquier header que se quiera setear en una secuencia PHP, no debe tener antes ninguna salida hacia el navegador porque va a fallar.  Si no son estos echos, son "echo's" por otra parte en la secuencia del PHP, o cualquier cosa que genere una salida, por ejemplo, un error que se muestra en pantalla, etc.